# how to print linux server variable on a html webpage

Tags: java, shell, unix, server, putty

Basically i want to create a webpage to monitor enterprise servers health status.
I need basic idea how i can connect to servers and print out FileSystem stat on a webpage on enterprise servers which are using putty IP.

Comment: Your question makes little sense. What on earth are `enterprise servers which are using putty IP`

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("my terminal command");

  p.waitFor();
  BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          p.getInputStream()));
  String line = "";
  String output = "";

  while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
    output += line + "\n";
  }

  System.out.println(output);
```